# posting text & image to Facebook from my app

Tags: android, facebook

I need to make my app post an image with some text to facebook.

Here's my code

```
               Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "text1");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text2");

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via..."));
```

It does post the image fine, but I can't find a way how to attach text to it.

[image]

While, for example, in instagram it does post both text & photo fine. Also notice the posting window is different.

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What by many android developer is classified as a bug in the facebook app is actually from their point of view a valid design decision.

Discussion on facebook [Android Intent Sharing is Broken](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423)

...
Our FB app handles the intent because it is an effective way for users to share content such as links (e.g. your app URL) on their Facebook. However, like I mentioned earlier, it is against our policy to pre-fill the message for our users because it erodes the authenticity of the user voice so our app does not accept the EXTRA_* fields .
...

Comment: If this is the real reason then why do they accept it in iOS 6?